# How to change the distance between month label and calender

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I want to know, how to decrease/increase the distance between month label and the calendar. There seem to be no "month label xshift" key.

Here is an MWE to play with:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8] 
  \calendar (mycal) [dates=2013-01-01 to 2013-01-last, week list, month label left vertical];
  \draw[red, thick] (mycal-2013-01-28) circle (7.3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With following result:

[image]

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I think that's the answer, that's basically what happens inside the `calendar` library as well (`month label left vertical` sets `every month/.append style{..., xshift=...}` too).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Yes, that's the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `every month` style but `.append style` your changes, otherwise you’ll overwrite all previous changes to the `every month`.

The `month label left vertical` style already appends `anchor=base east, xshift=-4.5ex, yshift=2.25ex, rotate=90`, the latter transformation is also the reason we need to use `yshift` to move our label in the *x* direction.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8] 
    \calendar (mycal) [
        dates=2013-01-01 to 2013-01-last,
        week list, 
        month label left vertical,
        every month/.append style={yshift=1em},
    ];
    \draw[red, thick] (mycal-2013-01-28) circle (7.3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]